# Error Json convirtiendo JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

He intentado de todas las maneras posible, tengo un script que recive un json que viene de un url de un web api, pero cuando intento pasarlo por `JSONObject` me lanza error, este es el pedazo del cédigo donde da error

```
Response responses = null;
try {
    responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
    json = responses.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("records");
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = c.getString("idintelisis");
    System.out.println("TESTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE: " + id);
}
```

Este es el error que envía

> 01-10 15:57:44.114 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"data":[{"idintelisis":71553,"observaciones":"Orden Compra
>   5593.","fecha":"05/18/2016","carro":"CIST-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":72023,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   5631.","fecha":"05/26/2016","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":72722,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   5788.","fecha":"06/29/2016","carro":"CE-07","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":73652,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   5871.","fecha":"07/20/2016","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":73660,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   5944.","fecha":"08/05/2016","carro":"CE-07","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":74296,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6064.","fecha":"09/02/2016","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75230,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6092.","fecha":"09/10/2016","carro":"CE-07","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75199,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6105.","fecha":"09/14/2016","carro":"CE-06","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":74567,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6112","fecha":"09/15/2016","carro":"CE-06","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":74893,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6115.","fecha":"09/16/2016","carro":"CE-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75123,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6190.","fecha":"10/03/2016","carro":"PT-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75234,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6190..","fecha":"10/03/2016","carro":"PT-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75451,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6249","fecha":"10/18/2016","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75668,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6261.","fecha":"10/20/2016","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":75840,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6324","fecha":"11/02/2016","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":76240,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6339.","fecha":"11/07/2016","carro":"PT-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":76147,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6346.","fecha":"11/08/2016","carro":"PT-03","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":77370,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6545","fecha":"12/28/2016","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":77343,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6551","fecha":"12/29/2016","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":77444,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6564","fecha":"01/03/2017","carro":"CE-04","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":77467,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra
>   6566","fecha":"01/03/2017","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"},{"idintelisis":77478,"observaciones":"Orden
>   Compra 6567","fecha":"01/03/2017","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"}]} 
>   of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 01-10
>   15:57:44.114 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java) 01-10 15:57:44.115
>   29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java) 01-10 15:57:44.115
>   29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java) 01-10 15:57:44.115
>   29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at
>   pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:102)
>   01-10 15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at
>   pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:68)
>   01-10 15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java) 01-10 15:57:44.115
>   29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) 01-10
>   15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java) 01-10
>   15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-10 15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-10 15:57:44.115 29347-18969/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)

En el log del error se incluye el json que está trayendo del url, es para un proyecto en Android

Answer (score 2):

El problema es el Json, lo indica el mensaje:

> value .... of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

No reconoce tu JSON, ya que el último elemento dentro del array "records" contiene un `,` lo cual provoca el un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elimina el último `,` y podrás procesar sin problema tu Json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ya realice la correccion que me indicaste pero aun sigue dando el mismo error @Elenasys

Comment: ok cambia: JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data"); según el  json ahora ese es el nombre del array "data" no "records".

Comment: @Elanasys si ya lo cambie y nada aun, llevo ya rato trabado en ese codigo siento que no es complicado pero no logro saber que hago mal

Comment: el error es en esta linea,  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json); cuando la lee se rompe y se va al catch de una vez

Comment: Antes de entrar a esa linea agrega aquí que contenido tiene la variable 
"json", veo que esta correctamente construido el objeto y no debería marcar algún error. =| ʢ◉ᴥ◉ʡ

Comment: Exacto y el objeto contiene el arrego completo, intente probar el codigo en un proyecto en blanco  y tambien me tira el mismo erro @Elenasys

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el formato de los datos:

```
{"records":["idintel ... 6567","fecha":"01/03/2017","carro":"CE-05","cargapkt":"2"},]}
```

Según lo que yo recuerdo de JSON, hay un "," que sobra al fin de los datos.

Y parece que ahora estas buscando "records" pero tu *array* ahora se llama "data" según log...

Comment: Hola, si ese último ","  no debe estar al final del último elemento del array "records", por esa razón no lo reconoce! =(